# Разбить массив в строку по шаблону

Tags: php

Можно ли как-то разбить массив в строку с помощью *implode()* по шаблону?
Например, есть массив

```
$query = array('fields' => array('Text', 'Name'), 'term' => 'AND');
$value = 5;
```

Нужно на выходе получить строку вида:

> Text = 5 OR Name = 5

Comment: $query = array('fields' => 'Text = 5 OR Name = 5');

Костыль :) я просто себе не могу представить такой метод

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну если только прям с implode() то как то так:

```
$query = array('fields' => array('Text', 'Name'), 'term' => 'AND');
$value = 5;

$result = implode(' = '. $value . ' ' . $query['term'] . ' ', $query['fields']) . ' = '. $value . ' ';
```

Не проверял, возможны помарки, но идея надеюсь понятна)